# Deployment of a ws-bpel process

Tags: web-services, wso2, apache-axis, bpel, business-process

I developed a ws-bpel process using wso2 developer studio.

But when I deployed it on the  wso2 business-application-server I got this error

[image: Bpel process deployment]

Also when I generated the .zip file of the ws-pel process, I didn't get any error.

Why my server connection is failed ?
Can any one help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your server is not properly running. Make sure you can access the management console to verify if the server is running properly